# How to delete specific session record by clicking on href?

Tags: php, session

I unable to delete specific record from session array. I want to delete specific row in table when I click on delete link.

```
<?php
session_start();

    if(isset($_GET["product"]) && isset($_GET["category"])){

        $nomProduct = trim($_GET["product"]);
        $category = trim($_GET["category"]);
        $_SESSION['product'][] = array(
            "nomProduct" => $nomProduct ,
            "category" =>  $category

        );

      //session_destroy();

       }
?>

    html table
              <table class="table">
                <?php foreach($_SESSION["product"] as $items) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <th width="250px"><?php echo $items['nomProduct']; ?></th>
                    <td><?php echo $items['category']; ?></td>
                    <td style="text-align: right"><a href="">Delete</a><td>
                </tr>
                <?php }?>

            </table>
```

Comment: try like this `$_SESSION['product'][$key]`

Comment: @MuhammadUsman can u please share code sample?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman How can I put it with href link?

Comment: PHP does not listen to clicks or other events. Your ` href` attribute is empty, you could set a link to a page with an *"action"* in the URL like `?delete=42` and proceed to delete an item if `$_GET['delete']` is set.

Comment: @AymDev can u please, show me how it works?

Comment: @YasirIqbal: try below code and let me know if it works.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I put code like this but its not working.              <?php
session_start();

    if(isset($_GET["product"]) && isset($_GET["category"])){

        $nomProduct = trim($_GET["product"]);
        $category = trim($_GET["category"]);
        $_SESSION['product'][] = array(
            "nomProduct" => $nomProduct ,
            "category" =>  $category

        );

        $key = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'key');
        unset($_SESSION['product'][$key]);
      //session_destroy();

       }
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your HTML

```
<table class="table">
<?php foreach($_SESSION["product"] as $key => $items) { ?>
  <tr>
    <th width="250px"><?php echo $items['nomProduct']; ?></th>
    <td><?php echo $items['category']; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align: right"><a href=?key="<?php echo $key; ?>">Delete</a><td>
   </tr>
 <?php }?>
</table>
```

Catch the array key and remove it from session array.

```
$key = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'key');
unset($_SESSION['product'][$key]);
```

Comment: key number is showing on url but record is not deleting

Comment: Can u please help? its deleting row

Comment: what I should write in INPUT_GET?

Answer (score 1):

`

```
$key=array_search($_GET['product'],$_SESSION['product']);
if($key!==false)
unset($_SESSION['product'][$key]);
$_SESSION["product"] = array_values($_SESSION["product"]);
```

`

Maybe this might help!
You need to find the key as this is an array.

EDIT:

Made an example for you, here when you click the link, it deletes the first name from the session array.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["user"] = ["fname"=>"William","lname"=>"Henry" ];
    if(isset($_GET["delete"]))
    {
        if($_GET["key"])
        {
            $key=$_GET["key"];
            unset($_SESSION['user'][$key]);
        }
    }
?>
```

HTML on the same page

```
<h1>
        <?php 
            if(isset($_SESSION["user"]["fname"]))echo $_SESSION["user"]["fname"]." "; 
            if(isset($_SESSION["user"]["lname"]))echo $_SESSION["user"]["lname"]; 
        ?>
</h1>
    <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?delete=user&key=fname" ?>">Delete First Name</a>
```

If you want to delete the lastname (lname), change the key=lname in the href of the link, hope this example helps in your case

Comment: In url its shows key but the record is not removing when I click on delete

Comment: make the href="" redirect to the same page with a something like delete=product,
the you can catch this with if(isset($_GET['delete'])) then run the above code

Comment: How can I set delete in href link?

Comment: href="page_url?delete=product"

Comment: I have <a href=coursesGet.php?key="<?php echo $key; ?> so where I should put delete=product ?

Comment: add  "&delete=product"
I just gave delete variable name as an example, you can use whatever you like

Comment: can u please make href link for me?

Comment: added an example that might help, you can change the keys and other variables to your need.